# Make return of a method/instance become an attribute

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I have a class A() include some method:

```
class A(self):
    def __init__ (self, x1, x2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
    def plus(self):
        X3 = self.x1 + self.x2
        return X3
```

How can I make X3 become an attribute which I can access by "self.X3" to use it for other methods
I am a newbie, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to simply make `X3` an attribute by prepending `self.`.  For example:

```
class A(self):
    def __init__ (self, x1, x2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
    def plus(self):
        self.X3 = self.x1 + self.x2
        return self.X3
```

I'm not sure it's the *best* approach, but it's hard to tell based on your question.

Comment: +1 for highlighting that it might not be the *best* approach. That is like a dozen man hours wasted when debugging for the magical `self.X3` being set from *somewhere*.

Comment: Think properties are probably the best way for this particular example.

Comment: @Alex, I think you're probably right, but then it's not clear what the `plus()` method should do, and it may be called from code we aren't shown.

Answer (score 1):

simply Change `X3 =` to: `self.X3=`

```
class A(self):
    def __init__ (self, x1, x2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
    def plus(self):
        self.X3 = self.x1 + self.x2
        return self.X3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
    def __init__ (self, x1, x2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
    def plus(self):
        self.X3 = self.x1 + self.x2
        return self.X3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(1, 2)
    print a.plus()
```

Give this a try.  I got some issues compiling when I tried adding (self) after class A.

Answer (score 0):

For this example, using a [property](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#property) is probably most appropriate. You can read more about the descriptor protocol (for which properties are syntactic sugar) [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

```
class A:
    def __init__ (self, x1, x2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
    @property
    def X3(self):
        return self.x1 + self.x2
```